# Repeating blocks in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
A = [[1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1]]
```

and from it, I'd like to create an array that looks like this:

```
B = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Where every element of `A` gets repeated in a square shape `n` times.
I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this -- can anybody think of something?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a block matrix.  [See this documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html).  For your specific application, each block would just be a constant (`A[i][j]`) times a matrix of ones (`np.ones(n)`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this does the job, although I'm open to other (faster or more elegant) suggestions!

```
np.repeat(np.repeat(A, n, axis=0), A, n, axis=1)
```

Comment: It all depends on how you look at it :)   Is it 3 blocks of `np.ones((2,2))`, or your `eye` expanded into (2,2) blocks?

Comment: `eye` expanded into (2,2) blocks. Actual use-case doesn't use `eye`, just thought it'd be the most straightforward example